# How to return HTTP response from HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Tags: http, spring-mvc, exception

I have some controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@AuthorizedRNUser
public Object index(UserStateVO userStateVO) {
    return userStateVO;
}
```

Also I have HandlerMethodArgumentResolver for UserStateVO parameter

```
public class UserStateArgumentHandlerResovler implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver{

    @Autowired
    RNService service;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(AuthorizedRNUser.class) && methodParameter.getParameterType() == UserStateVO.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
        UserStateVO userState = service.getUserState();
        if (isNull(userState))
            // here i need to return 403 HTTP response
            throw new RuntimeException("User is not allowed");
        return userState;
    }
}
```

And if the UserStateVO is null I need to return 403 HTTP response, but I do not know is it possible? How best to check UserStateVO and pass it into a controller or return HTTP response?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same method as handling exceptions in MVC [exception-handling-in-spring-mvc](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Add your custom exception, e.g

```
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public BadRequestException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

And either annotate it with `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason = "User is not allowed")` or add `@ControllerAdvice` class with method like

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { BadRequestException.class })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> handleBadRequestException(BadRequestException e) {
   Map<String, String> retMessages = new HashMap<>();
   retMessages.put("message", e.getMessage());
   return retMessages;
}
```

what remains is just to throw it

```
if (isNull(userState))
        // here i need to return 403 HTTP response
        throw new BadRequestException("User is not allowed");
```